# How to schedule a Jenkins job each 15 minutes

Tags: jenkins, schedule, hour, minute

I need to schedule a jenkins job each 15 minutes.

Currently i'm using the `Build periodically` feature but that enables me to schedule the job once in 1 hour maximum.

What i got now is:

`15 * * * *` is running the job HOURLY (each XX:15)

`15 0 * * *` is running the job DAILY on 00:15

What is the right cron-expression that will run the job every 15 minutes?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To run the job at a regular interval of 15 minutes you have to write it like below:

`*/15 * * * *`  - Will run at every 15 minutes (may be at XX:01,XX:16,XX:31 ..)

Where */15 specifies no matter whatever is Hour (H) run it at 15 every minutes.

Comment: To spread load evenly, you should use `H/15 * * * *`, that way if you have multiple jobs configured at regular interval of 15mins, jenkins will not run all of them at the same time.